# Quicksort is extremely slow

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array which has 4 columns and 1921980 rows `string array = new string[1921980, 4]`. The array should be sorted by the values in the fourth column. So I started with Bubble Sort and well it's ridiculously slow, even parallelized. It also produces high CPU utilization. I switched to Quick Sort (recursive) and things get much faster. The problem is that I call 2 methods while sorting:

- `Console.Write` to show the progress
- `StringToInt32` custom method, which is faster than `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse`

But this produces a StackOverFlowException after some time. So I decided to go with Quick Sort (iterative). And it feels like Bubble Sort. I guess that my code got some issues.

```
    static int StringToInt32(string s)
    {
        int tmp = 0;

        switch (s[0])
        {
            case '-':
                for (int counter = 1; counter < s.Length; counter++)
                {
                    tmp = tmp * 10 + (s[counter] - '0');
                }

                tmp *= -1;
                return tmp;
                break;
            default:
                for (int counter = 0; counter < s.Length; counter++)
                {
                    tmp = tmp * 10 + (s[counter] - '0');
                }
                return tmp;
                break;
        }
    }

    static void QuickSort(ref string[,] array, int length)
    {
        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        stack.Push(length - 1);
        stack.Push(0);

        int percent = -1;

        int look = 0;

        while (stack.Count != 0)
        {
            /**
            * Pop array or sub array start and end index
            */
            int left = stack.Pop();
            int right = stack.Pop();
            int newPivotIndex = Partition(ref array, left, right);

            /**
            *  divide right i.e. second sub array from newPivotIndex+1 to right
            *  here newPivotIndex+1 is index where right elements are greater or = than pivot
            *  use stack for storing array index and in while loop pop that right sub array indexes.
            */
            if ((newPivotIndex + 1) < right)
            {
                stack.Push(right);
                stack.Push(newPivotIndex + 1);
            }
            /**
            *  divide sub array from left to mid or newPivotIndex-1
            *  here newPivotIndex-1 is index where left elements are lesser or = than pivot
            *  use stack for storing array index and in while loop pop that left sub array indexes.
            */
            if ((newPivotIndex - 1) > left)
            {
                stack.Push(newPivotIndex - 1);
                stack.Push(left);
            }

            look++;
            if (look * 100 / length != percent)
            {
                percent = look * 100 / length;
                Console.Write("\r{0}%", percent);
            }
        }

        Console.Write("\r100%");
    }

    static int GetMedianPivot(ref string[,] array, int left, int right)
    {
        int mid = ((left + right) / 2);
        /** middle number of array is less than left number of array 
         *  then Swap middle and left number
         */
        if (StringToInt32(array[mid, 3]) < StringToInt32(array[left, 3]))
        {
            Swap(ref array, left, mid);
        }
        /** rightmost number of array is less than left number of array 
         *  then Swap right and left number
         */
        if (StringToInt32(array[right, 3]) < StringToInt32(array[left, 3]))
        {
            Swap(ref array, left, right);
        }
        /**
        * now right number is less than mid then Swap number which 
        * shifts median of three numbers into mid position
        */
        if (StringToInt32(array[right, 3]) < StringToInt32(array[mid, 3]))
        {
            Swap(ref array, mid, right);
        }
        /**
        * Shift Median or pivot from mid to rightmost position
        * i.e. out of partitioning index
        */
        Swap(ref array, mid, right);
        /**return pivot number value which is right most now.**/
        return StringToInt32(array[right, 3]);
    }

    static int Partition(ref string[,] array, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot = StringToInt32(array[right, 3]); ;

        /**
        * Initialize low = left i.e. start index of array or logical sub-array
        * Initialize high = right-1 i.e. end index of array or logical sub array;
        * becuase right is pivot element so start from right-1;
        */
        int low = left;
        int high = right - 1;
        do
        {
            while (StringToInt32(array[low, 3]) < pivot && low < right - 1)
            {
                low++;
            }

            while (StringToInt32(array[high, 3]) >= pivot && high > left)
            {
                high--;
            }

            /** 
            * Swap elements when any left element is greater than pivot or  
            * any right element is less than pivot.
            */
            if (low < high)
            {
                Swap(ref array, low, high);
                low++;
                high--;
            }
        } while (low < high);
        /**
        *  Swap right most pivot to its right position i.e. at low, then 
        *  left elements are lesser and right elements are greater than pivot.
        */
        if (StringToInt32(array[low, 3]) > pivot)
        {
            Swap(ref array, low, right);
        }

        return low;
    }

    static void Swap(ref string[,] array, int i, int j)
    {
        string[] buffer = new string[4];

        buffer[0] = array[i, 0];
        buffer[1] = array[i, 1];
        buffer[2] = array[i, 2];
        buffer[3] = array[i, 3];

        array[i, 0] = array[j, 0];
        array[i, 1] = array[j, 1];
        array[i, 2] = array[j, 2];
        array[i, 3] = array[j, 3];

        array[j, 0] = buffer[0];
        array[j, 1] = buffer[1];
        array[j, 2] = buffer[2];
        array[j, 3] = buffer[3];
    }
```

Comment: Creating new array every swap, converting strings to int in every comparison etc... Of course it will be slow. And I would be very surprised if custom int conversion really is faster than the ones provided in the framework, but guess it’s possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't you convert all the strings to ints first and then sort that rather than converting every single iteration/swap/pivot/etc? Wouldnt a `int[,] ` be more appropriate? If you must, convert to that first,  sort it, then copy back to the string array using ToString. You're doing a lot of extra work every time when you could do it up front once

Comment: There's no question here. You wrote a really bad implementation of quicksort, it was very slow, and... that's a story not a question.  What's your specific, answerable question?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use refs everywhere? Array is already a pointer, you can use it efficiently as a parameter, using ref is not faster.  Sami Kuhmonen has some important observations too.

I would use something along this lines:

```
int ArrSize = 1921980;
long[] tmp = new long[ArrSize];
for (int i = 0; i < ArrSize; ++i)
{
    tmp[i] = (((long)StringToInt32(array[i, 3])) << 32) | (long)i;
}

Array.Sort(tmp);

string[,] array2 = new string[ArrSize, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < ArrSize; ++i)
{
    int index = (int)tmp[i];
    array2[i, 0] = array[index, 0];
    array2[i, 1] = array[index, 1];
    array2[i, 2] = array[index, 2];
    array2[i, 3] = array[index, 3];
}
```

Are negative numbers a problem? Casting negative int to long produdes 1 in the upper 32 bits. But they are shifted out in our case. Upper 32 bits are in the end equal to original number in the array. For comparing, (it is not done that way, but you can [imagine that is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Comparison_(ordering))) you compare bit by bit and if you find a difference you yield the result. From that you can see, that lower 32 bits do not matter as long as there is a difference in upper 32 bits. `(long)i` is safe because i is index in the array and it is always positive. `(int)tmp[i]` just discards upper 32 bits a does not alter lower bits in any way. Conclusion is, it is not a problem.

Another question may be, is this stable, that means, does this preserve order of items in original sequence for items that are considered equal? If they are equal they do not differ in the upper 32 bits. The lower 32 bits are index in the original array, that means they represent the original order. If upper 32 bits are equal, you compare by lower 32 bits, that means by order in original sequence. It may be a bit surprising, but sorting this way is stable even in case `Array.Sort` itself is not.

Comment: This is much better than I wrote...does it have a concern if the item is negative?...the sign bit being a 1 redefines the meaning of the rest... Wondering if it's a problem...not sure